# ScrollIntoView in GridView doesn't work

Tags: c#, gridview, winrt-xaml, scrollviewer

the `ScrollIntoView()` method does not work for me, but I was able to narrow the problem a little.

We have changed the style for the `GridView` as follows:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
            <Border>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" >
                    <Grid >

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="38" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="120"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Border x:Name="NewGroupPlaceHolderFirst" Grid.Column="0" ... />

                        <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"  ... />

                        <Border x:Name="NewGroupPlaceHolderLast" Grid.Column="2"  ... />

                    </Grid>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

When the `ItemsPresenter` stands alone within the `ScrollViewers` the method works.
but the borders are needed to create a new Group.

Is there a possible solution to get this method work?

regards,
oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement scrolling by yourself:

1. Find the ScrollViewer by examining the childrens of the GridView with the VisualTreeHelper.
2. Determine the horizontal/vertical offset of the item you want to scroll to.
3. Scroll to the position.

   var offset = targetItem.TransformToVisual(scrollViewer).TransFormPoint(new Point(0,0)).X;
   scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(offset);